# App "Ready for Sale", appeared in App store, then disappeared after 2 hours?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes

I just submitted my first app July 16th and it got the "ready for sale" signal yesterday. About 22 hours later it was finally in the app store via direct link (not searchable). I got a few of my friends to download it and it worked flawlessly. But 2 hours later, the app was no longer available in the app store, the direct link doesn't even work :/

I was just wondering if this is normal or unusual. Please share your experience/thoughts. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is perfectly normal. It happened with both of my apps. I do not know for certain, but I think it is because the data is being processed, and everything has to be updated before it can stay permanently.